# Multi nodes hadoop cluster configuration

Tags: hadoop2

I'm new to Hadoop cluster and trying to deploy a multi-node cluster on ubuntu 15.10 with ONE master and TWO slaves. After configuration, there's TWO active nodes(two slaves). However, when I tried hadoop example program below

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar pi 3 100
```

I got an error of `connection refused`:

> Job job_1459774851310_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1459774851310_0001 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1459774851310_0001_000002. Got exception: java.net.ConnectException: Call From ubuntu/127.0.1.1 to ubuntu:36380 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

To deploy this cluster, I disabled ipv6 in all machines, and edited configuration files as following shows:

In file `core-site.xml`:

```
fs.defaultFS = hdfs://master:8020
```

In file `hdfs-site.xml`:

```
dfs.namenode.name.dir = $HADOOP_PREFIX/namenode
dfs.datanode.data.dir = $HADOOP_PREFIX/datanode
```

In file `yarn-site.xml`:

```
yarn.resourcemanager.address = master:8084
yarn.resourcemanager.schedular.address = master:8085
yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address = master:8086
yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address = master:8087
yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address = master:8088
yarn.nodemanager.aux-services = mapreduce_shuffle
```

In file `mapred_site.xml`

```
mapreduce.framework.name = yarn
mapreduce.jobhistory.address = master:10020
mapreduce.jobhistory.address = master:19888
```

Those 4 files are the same on all machines.

Where did I make mistakes? How to fix it?

In file `slaves`, I wrote only the IP addresses of two slaves.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $HOSTNAME` on your master and slave machine? And do you have proper entries in **/etc/hosts**? I am asking this because of "java.net.ConnectException: Call From **ubuntu/127.0.1.1** to **ubuntu:36380**", from where hadoop picking this names?

Comment: echo of `$HOSTNAME` is `hdmaster`, `hdslave` and `hdslave2`. I've added 3 IPs of master and slaves into `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Then you should updated **master** with **hdmaster** in `core-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`, `yarn-site.xml`, `mapred_site.xml` and in `master` file.